# Type hinting Python enum staticmethod where literal types are defined

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

In the code below, the `direction` attribute of the `Horizontal` dataclass is type hinted to only allow 3 of the 5 values from the `Direction` enum. I want to be able to return an enum value from dynamic input using the `from_string` static method which falls back to Direction.UNKNOWN if the string doesn't match any of the enum values. In practice the code works but `mypy` complains with the following error:

> 27: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Direction", variable has type "Literal[Direction.LEFT, Direction.RIGHT, Direction.UNKNOWN]")  [assignment]
> Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

This is understandable because we're getting a generic `Direction` instance back from the static method rather than one of the specific 3 that are type hinted. Are there any ways round this that would satisfy `mypy` other than removing the return type of the `from_string` method?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import auto, StrEnum
from typing import Literal

class Direction(StrEnum):
    DOWN = auto()
    LEFT = auto()
    RIGHT = auto()
    UP = auto()
    UNKNOWN = auto()

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(value: str) -> 'Direction':
        try:
            return Direction(value.lower())
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return Direction.UNKNOWN

@dataclass
class Horizontal:
    direction: Literal[Direction.LEFT, Direction.RIGHT, Direction.UNKNOWN] = Direction.UNKNOWN

horizontal = Horizontal()
horizontal.direction = Direction.LEFT
print(f'{horizontal=}')
horizontal.direction = Direction.from_string(input('Enter a direction: '))
print(f'{horizontal=}')
```

Comment: The error seems entirely correct - you don't know that, even if the method does return a value, it will correspond to a horizontal direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining new enums that are sub-sets of your overall Enum instead:

```py
from enum import auto, StrEnum


class Direction(StrEnum):
    LEFT = auto()
    RIGHT = auto()
    UP = auto()
    DOWN = auto()
    UNKNOWN = auto()


Horizontal = StrEnum("Horizontal", [(Direction.LEFT.name, Direction.LEFT),
                                 (Direction.RIGHT.name, Direction.LEFT),
                                 (Direction.UNKNOWN.name, Direction.UNKNOWN)])
Vertical = StrEnum("Vertical", [(Direction.UP.name, Direction.UP),
                             (Direction.DOWN.name, Direction.DOWN),
                             (Direction.UNKNOWN.name, Direction.UNKNOWN)])


my_direction: Horizontal = Horizontal.LEFT
print(f'{my_direction=}')
my_direction = Horizontal[input('Enter a direction: ')]
print(f'{my_direction=}')
```

This will give you the ability to use the sub-set where appropriate in code and keep the correct typing. In this instance, if the User tries to enter UP or DOWN, an exception will be raised, which I think is what you want. This is a runtime check, not a mypy check.